# How to connect mixer's mono aux send to stereo input of FX unit?

Tags: mixer, cable, aux-sends

I have a Mackie 1402VLZ Pro mixing desk. I want to use one of the sends to hook up an [Axoloti](http://www.axoloti.com/) unit for use as an FX unit.

As I understand it, the send jack socket from the Mackie is mono, and has the summed stereo signals from the mixer track inputs. The Axoloti has stereo in and out jack sockets.

What is the appropriate cable to connect from the Mackie send to the Axoloti input?

(The Mackie has stereo aux returns, so I have a stereo -> 2x mono cable running from Axoloti out to Mackie in.

I have a spring reverb connected to the other Mackie aux send, so I only have one usable send jack socket on the mixer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, sends are mono and channels 7 through 14 get their left/right programs summed at the send if in fact there is stereo content present.

The documentation for that Axoloti unit makes it clear that the output wants to see a TRS cable, and it wants to be in stereo...but I couldn't find any mention of whether the input is as particular.

if the Axoloti unit really does require a "stereo" input, you could probably get away with using a "dual mono" splitter cable from the mixer's send output.

Comment: Thanks for that - the Axoloti has a single stereo input jack - so the question is, should i wire up a mono to stereo cable? And is that just tip to tip, tip to ring, sleeve to sleeve, or are resistors or some other voodoo required?

Comment: the voodoo would be making up a crazy TS to TRS cable...The tip of the TS end would connect to both the tip and the ring of the TRS cable. Sleeve is still sleeve.

Comment: It looks like resistors are required if going the other way - i.e. from stereo out to mono in. See here: https://www.gearslutz.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/738925-stereo-mono-cable-correct-resistors-does-anyone-make-sell-one.html
But in this case (mono -> stereo) wiring without resistors seems like the way to go.

Comment: right...and the impedance seen by the send output will essentially be halved, so hopefully it can cope.